# PHP limiting the ability of interations to current number of orders, instead of showing for all matches

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

**The current problem** - I have one small shirt available and 6 reservations. The six reservations for a small t shirt will ALL blink green showing that reservation can be filled..... but I only have one shirt. As soon as one reservation for the shirt is filled, the other 5 reservations would stop blinking green but it makes it look like all six reservations might be able to be filled.

**The change** - I need to alter the code I have written to look at the 6 reservations for a small shirt, see that maybe only two small shirts have currently been made and then ONLY have two reservations display that flashing green that they can be filled. The other 4 would not show a status change since there are no shirts for them yet.

I am not sure if that is best done in the PHP by something like limiting the iterations or in the jQuery by changing how callB attaches its order ready information to the main reservation div. Is it is it best to limit things there? Or change how it ataches so somehow it reads what each reservation is looking for?

The code uses PHP, AJAX and Jquery in addition to linking to the DB.

**The AJAX/Jquery**

```
    jQuery( document ).on( 'popup/show', (event, id ) => {
        if (id === 123){   
            async: false
            function pollServer() {
            callA();
            callC();
            callB();
           } 
            pollServer();
            setInterval(pollServer, 150000);  
    

    var isActive = true;
    //start function callA which gets the the current waitlist for the shirts and populates it
    function callA() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            data: {action: 'waiting_list'},
            type: 'post',
            url: my_ajax.ajax_url,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data) {
             
var html = '';
jQuery.each( data, function(key,value){
callB(value.id_order, value.Wait, value.Size);

//builds the t-shirt order waitinglist
html +='<div class=" d_flex accordion-header ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-accordion-icons ui-corner-all" id="res_'+value.id_order+'" >';
html +='<div class="flx3">'+value.Customer_Name'</div>';
html +='<div class="flx1">'+ value.Size+ '</div>';
html +='<div class="flx1>' +value.Status+ '</div>';
html +='<div class="flx1>' +value.Wait+ '</div>'; 
html +='</div>'; //ends building the waitlist div for each reservation

//start building the container for the dropdown which is where a t-shirt order can be filled. 
html +='<div id="t_options_'+value.id_order+'" class="d_flex_plus ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" style ="display:none">';

//This is the dead div with no display I later attach the dom content to when an order can be filled. See callB
html +='<div id="cid_'+value.id_order'" style="display: none"></div>';
html +='</div>';  
}); //end juery .each fuction for callA
jQuery('#waitlist').html(html);
            }//end of success function 
          }); //end AJAX call
        } //end of function A
    
//builds and queries the db to see how many of what t-shirt type are currently available right now
        function callB(id_order, Wait, Size) {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
            jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: my_ajax.ajax_url,      
            data: { action: 'tshirt_options_function',
            cid : id_order,
            Wait_Time: Wait,      
            },
success: function (data) {
// this is where and how I am getting the t-shirt ready div to attach to each individual reservation div when they come ready
jQuery(data).insertAfter('#cid_' + id_order)
}
} //end success 
}); //end ajax call for function CallB
}, 500); //end setTimeout
} //end function callB
    } //ends if id of this popup
}); //ends .on pop up
```

**the PHP**

```
  // the order list
    function waiting_list() {           
        global $wpdb;   
        $resultss = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id_order, Customer_Name, Size,ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(now(),order_Created))/60,0) as Wait, Status FROM t_shirt_reservations  Status = 'Waiting'");
            if($resultss){
        echo json_encode($resultss);}
        
        die;}

    ///connects to AJAX callB
function tshirt_options_function() {
global $wpdb;
// passes the total amount of time a customer has been waiting in days for the order to be filled
$wait = $_POST['Wait_Time'];
// passes customer id for the reservation
$cid = $_POST['cid']; 
// quiries db to see how many of what size shirt are needed based on current shirt reservations
$t_size = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT t_shirt_size_needed FROM t_shirt_reservations WHERE id_order = $cid");
// quiries db to see what options might work based on neck size as it relates to small, medium , large etc
$present_tshirt_options = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT shirt_id, shirt_size FROM t-shirts WHERE $t_size BETWEEN `Min_neck_size` and `Max_neck_size`");
//displays the common size such as medium, large, small xl, etc based on neck size max
$shirt_type = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT `shirt_Type` FROM t-shirts WHERE  `Max_neck_size` = $t_size LIMIT 1");
        
            
        if(!empty($present_tshirt_options)){
              echo '<div id="available_'.$cid.'" class="d_flex">';
                echo /*'<th class="bg_clear" >' . "<i class='fas fa-level-up-alt seat-options-icon fa-rotate-90'></i>" .  '</th>', */'<div class="flx1  ">' . "Neck Size". '</div>', '<div class="flx2 ">' . "Common Shirt Size". '</div>',  '<div class="flx1 ">' . "Fill Order Button". '</div>';
                echo '</div>';  
            
        
        foreach($present_tshirt_options as $shirts){    
            $shirt_id=$shirts->shirt_id;
            $shirt_size=$shirts->shirt_size;
            echo '<div>';
            echo '<div class="d_flex">';
            echo '<div class=" flx1">' . $shirt_size . '</div>';
           echo '<div class="flx1">' . "<button id='fillorder' class='button' onclick='fillorder($shirt_id, $cid)'></button>" . '</div>';
           echo '</div>';
            
        }
        }
            else{
                
           echo '<div> no shirts yet available</div>';
        }    
            die;
        }
```

**The html**

```
function CurrentWaitlist(){ ?>  
<div id="waitlist" style="display: inline-block"></div>
<?php   }
add_shortcode('CurrentWaitlist', 'CurrentWaitlist');
```

**Background**
I am in the process of programming a small fulfillment system. I didnt think it through all the way before I started and have been learning along the way. Now that I am to the last part of the logic, I could use help on the approach and what I would need to change.

I currently have a system where someone can enter a reservation for a t-shirt they would like to order. They are placed on a waiting list while the shirt is hand made.  Each shirt reservation is displayed in its own div on an orders screen. When the shirt has been made and is ready, that is entered in the system. The code sees this and then shows a status change of blinking the div green that needs the small t-shirt.  The reservations with a small t shirt show that green status change so that people know when it can be packed and shipped.

The initial design flaw was that I didnt separate out the way a shirt that was ready would be assigned to the reservation for the shirt. Despite passing along the reservation ID, right now the code looks at how many small size shirt reservations there are and simply shows a status change for **all** reservations with the size small if there is even one shirt available.

Comment: It would be much easier to understand and help you if I could see all the code, I'm assuming this is not all of it as you make a reference to a function called "CallD" which is not defined. Also the html would be nice so that I can run your code to help me debug and play with it. Thanks.

Comment: There are thousands of lines of code and so I removed code that wasnt realivent to the question. Calld is just the code that turns the divs green. Ill remove above the reference to it since that doesnt matter and I am trying to keep it easy for people to read. I did add the HTML

Comment: Perhaps just pass a variable in the json that tells the js how many shirts are available and then the js can handle which ones to make flash and etc? This seems too easy of a solution but it would help to know why something like this would not be possible.

Comment: @ripytide I like the thought of it. How would it limit how many are attached via the .html way I am currently attaching it to that blank div? Also, since it isnt just about counting the base number of shirts but rather the number in each size what would somethign like that look like then?

Comment: I am very unfamiliar with how your system works but from a very high level point of view this is how I would picture a potential solution: The client asks the server if any of the orders it has currently can be fulfilled. The server side would then look at its stock and decide for each element whether it can or not be fulfilled, it should send its finding back to the user and the ones that can be fulfilled should then blink green. Once a user clicks the blinking green light then it should send a request which actually assigns the stock to that order.

Comment: Thanks. That is basically what I have set u. My hang up is listed in detail under the problem and seems to be with the way I am sending back and attaching the DOM content when an order can be filled. I am not sure how to restrict that only to the number of availabilities if that makes sense? In callB in this line `jQuery(data).insertAfter('#cid_' + id_order)` is how I am attaching but it just attaches to any and all without validation. Its that validation component I am struggling with

Comment: Generally speaking validation of which you require should always be done on the server side and then the results returned back to the client. As for the specifics of how to implement the solution, it is very hard for me to help due to the complexity of your said problem.

Comment: right that is why I was thinking this is done in PHP but I am not sure where to start on something like that beyond what I already have. That is what I am asking for help on. All the code above is the realivent code for these functions

Comment: If you have 6 orders for blue t-shirts and you have 4 in stock then I would sort the orders by the date they were set and then loop through the orders. For each order decide if you have > 0 available stock, if you do then assign the stock and decrement the available stock and continue looping until you have no more stock.

Comment: best way to do that through a `foreach` loop or some other tool?

Comment: a careful while loop would do the job. While (stock > 0). Alternatively you could use a for loop and break once stock <= 0.

Comment: easy if there was only one size, but correct me if I am wrong, this would have to be a foreach in this instance since I need to get the stock of small, the stock of medium, etc?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227773/discussion-between-ripytide-and-user14955679).